# How can I add google profile or facebook profile link into my website..?

Tags: facebook-like, profile, google-plus

How can I add [google profile](http://plus.google.com/116791117116412845805/) or [facebook profile](http://www.facebook.com/ProgrammingPad) link into my website..?

Comment: Do you want to link to your profile, or actually embed your profile page, e.g., in an iframe?

Comment: Please do not forget to accept an answser.

Answer (score 3):

A simple html link should be fine :

```
<a href="http://plus.google.com/116791117116412845805/">My Google Profile</a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/ProgrammingPad">My Facebook Profile</a>
```

You can also generate the html code for a [Google Profile badge](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/) and a [Facebook Profile badge](https://www.facebook.com/badges/) if you would like more features.

If you website is managed by a tool like Blogger or WordPress, many plugin exists to easily generate links.

Answer (score 1):

Follow what @poiuytrez said.

Also, While adding your Google Plus profile... You can also use [rel="author"](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986) tag. And from your G+ profile add your website link the [Contributor To](http://plus.google.com/me/about/edit/co) section.

```
<a href="http://plus.google.com/116791117116412845805/" rel="author">My Google Profile</a>
```

This way your profile might show up in search results as an author. See below.
[image]